# splitting pipeline in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with the following features:
visitor_id, feature_1, feature_2, ..., feature_100, truth_labels

I implemented the following model on sklearn:

**1st step**: scaling `df.drop(['visitor_id', 'truth_labels'], axis=1)` using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()`

**2nd step**: clustering `df.drop(['visitor_id', 'truth_labels'], axis=1)` using `sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans()` in **10 clusters**. Set `df['cluster']` to corresponding clusters.

**3rd step**: fit **10** `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()` on `df.drop(['visitor_id'], axis=1)`, one per cluster.

I have two questions:

1- Is it possible to build a `Pipeline` in order to aggregate these three steps? In particular, how can I specify that I want to train 10 distinct `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()` models on my data splitted by clusters?

2- Is it possible to save this full pipeline? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.

1) You can implement your own logic for pipeline step. 
You can find detailed example [in sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#example-hetero-feature-union-py).

In your case it would be:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline

class TenLogisticRegressionsClassifier(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):


    def __init__(self, N=10):
        self.estimators = { i:LogisticRegression() for i in range(N)  }


    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        for k,v in self.estimators.items():
            # Here some logic to divide dataset
            v.fit(newX, newY)

    def predict(self, X, y=None):
        for k,v in self.estimators.items():
            # Here some logic to divide dataset
            v.predict(newX)

pipeline = Pipeline([('something',   TenLogisticRegressionsClassifier())])
# or
pipeline = make_pipeline(TenLogisticRegressionsClassifier())
```

2) Answer is [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143829/sklearn-how-to-save-a-model-created-from-a-pipeline-and-gridsearchcv-using-jobli)

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'pipeline.pkl')
# or, if you want 1 file:
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'filename.pkl', compress = 1)
```

Then you can load it and use:

```
pipeline_loaded = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```

Comment: Could you add a brief summary of the SO link? Sometimes SO questions are closed (or deleted by their original questioner) so there is still a chance of linkrot, and it would be nice to have a self-contained answer.